# Irreversibly terminated terminal session

Tags: bash, terminal, shell

I was trying to update bash in my terminal and I have managed to accidentally log out and terminate bash. Now, whenever I open the terminal the following info is displayed:

Last login: Sat Jan 25 10:53:24 on ttys000
login: /usr/local/Cellar/bash/5.0.0/bin/bash: No such file or directory

[Process completed]

As the session is terminated I cannot type anything and I have no idea how to make terminal run bash again. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is on macOS

- Open Preferences in Terminal (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd>)
- On the "General" tab, switch from default login shell to user-specific and enter `/bin/bash` as the path for the shell supplied with macOS. Or use `/usr/local/bin/bash` to use the version installed via Homebrew.